# How can I print the following pattern with the for statement?

Tags: c#, for-loop

How can I print the following pattern with the for statement?

> AAAA 
> AAAB
> AABB
> ABBB
> BBBB

What I tried to do:

Code:

```
 int stars = 4;
 for (int row = stars; row >= 1; row--)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("A");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            
        }
```

Comment: Please add a label with the language that you are using. Also you never write a `B` so ofcourse it will never appear at the pattern.

Comment: @MarkBaijens it should be C#, because `Console.Write` is a C# method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.write?view=net-5.0

Comment: @VitalyOlegovitch I know it's likely C# although you can not be sure. Perhaps there is another language we don't know of that uses the same syntax. Therefore you should always specify it when posting a question. It's also better for the search algorithm when searching for questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You where almost there.

1. I made a small change in the first for loop to add another row (`>= 1` to `>= 0`). We need 5 rows for 4 stars, 6 rows for 5 stars, etc.
2. Compared the second for loop to stars as well because we want 4 values on each row (when `stars` is 4).
3. Added an if statement to check if we need to write an `A` or `B` based on the iteration number of both loops.

See code below:

```
int stars = 4;
for(int i = stars; i >= 0; i--) {
    for(int j = 0; j < stars; j++) {
        if(i > j) {
            Console.Write('A');
        }
        else {
            Console.Write('B');
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();               
}
```